# Automatically invoking BUTTON_CLICK event according to IF statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to invoke Button_click event if the condition gets TRUE. But it's not working because of some reasons. Can you help please?
Thank you.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       button1.Click+=button1_Click;

    }


    private void CheckFile()
    {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo("c:\\test.txt");
        if (info.Length > 0)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
          //this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
            MessageBox.Show("FILE is not empty"); //just for check

        }
    }                   

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            MessageBox.Show("Message POP UP");            
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.CheckFile();
    MessageBox.Show("CheckFile called");    

}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Invoke it like this

```
button1_Click(this.button1, new EventArgs())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send two arguments to the Button Click event handler.

1.soure of the event.
2.Event arguments.

Try This:

```
        object sender = new object() ;
        EventArgs e=new EventArgs();
        button1_Click(sender,e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply
just modify your button1_Click method like this:

```
private void button1_Click(EventArgs e)
{            
        MessageBox.Show("Message POP UP");            
}
```

And call it like that:

```
button1_Click(new EventArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//but is the Button you wanna click
buttonClick(but, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left , 1, 0, 0, 0 ));
```